# Вращение вокруг точки правильной стороной в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал вращение самолетика над указанной точкой с помощью transform.RotateAround. Но беда в том, что он вращается носом к центру. Как сделать, чтоб он вращался правильно - боком к центру? Не могу разобраться никак. П.С. - 2D.

`transform.RotateAround(point, Vector3.forward, 45 * Time.deltaTime);`

[image]

По умолчанию RotateAround, я так понимаю работает против часовой стрелки. Так что если перед началом его выполнения самолет оказывается справа от точки, вокруг которой должен летать, то всё происходит правильно - летит носом вперед.
[image]

Если слева от точки, то летит, соответственно, попой вперед.

[image]

Если снизу или сверху, то летит тем или иным боком вперед.

Вот вопрос - как его держать всегда носом вперед при облете точки...

Comment: Для начала, приложите код

Comment: Код к вопросу можно приложить, используя кнопку "Править" под текстом вопроса. Код следует вставлять между одинарными кавычками: ` (одна строка) либо тройными кавычками: ``` (многострочный)

Comment: А не проще посадить самолёт на пустой gameobject в нужной позиции/повороте и вращать этот пустой gameobject?

Comment: Выглядит сложно, учитывая, что точка не стационарная. Она выбирается в процессе полёта, он сходит с маршрута, летает над ней, потом возвращается на маршрут. Должно быть как то проще... Но не знаю как))

Comment: Полурешение нашёл. Если до RotateAround выполнить AngleAxis на 90 градусов, то с одной стороны маршрута (например слева) начинает летать правильно, а вот с другой - попой вперёд...